# Snowflake - Date string has T character, can't convert to datetime

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have several columns that look like this with a `T` and `+`: `2020-04-11T21:00:09+0000`

I want to convert them to datetime if possible, I've tried `to_timestamp_ntz()` and `to_date()`:

```
to_timestamp_ntz('2020-04-11T21:00:09+0000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF+00')
```

but I keep seeing:

> Can't parse '2020-04-11T21:00:09+0000' as timestamp with format...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of format:

```
SELECT to_timestamp_ntz('2020-04-11T21:00:09+0000', 
                        'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZHTZM') AS res
```

To handle `T` it needs to be provided as `"T"`.

Output:

[image]

---

The pattern `"..."`  inside format works for arbitrary text:

```
SELECT to_timestamp_ntz('2020-04-11aaaa21:00:09+0000', 
                        'YYYY-MM-DD"aaaa"HH24:MI:SSTZHTZM') AS res
-- 2020-04-11 21:00:09.000
```

Comment: thanks! this worked also and thanks for explaining it helped when you added 'aaa'

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to specify a date/time format to skip over a character like that. You may have to do something like this:

```
select to_timestamp_ntz(replace('2020-04-11T21:00:09+0000', 'T', ' '), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SSTZHTZM')
```

Comment: @GregPavlik  for workaround.  It is possible to handle `T` without replacing it. Please check my answer.