# Extracting date from varchar with timezone in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have some sample data in snowflake as follows;

```
created_at
----------

2022-06-10T18::35::57
2022-06-10T18::35::57
```

The datatype of this column is VARCHAR(16777216), I am trying to filter for the rows  with date June 10,2022. Here is my query;

```
select *
 from table
 where to_date(created_at) = date('2022-06-10', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

But this gives me following error; `Date '2022-06-10T18::35::57' is not recognized`. If we replace `to_date` by `try_to_date` then we get 0 rows. Unfortunately I can't go to backend and change the properties of the table. Therefore, I need to resort to sql datetime functions.

Can I please get help here, on how to fix above errors? thanx

Answer (score 0):

Using `LEFT` to get date part:

```
where to_date(LEFT(created_at, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD') = date('2022-06-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: @ Lukasz Szozda appreciate your. reply. But what if we want to some sort of ranking in this table based on dates and choosing the most recent row. can you kindly advise?

Comment: @jay This is completely different question, but for that you could always use `QUALIFY`. An example could be: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72576393/5070879

Comment: @jay Also in case you you need to handle extra characters using date format only: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72574909/snowflake-date-column-has-character-cant-convert-to-datetime/72575622#72575622

Answer (score 0):

There are  two issues here -
1 - It is not a date but a timestamp
2 - usage of '::' rather then standard ':' in time portion

Below will not work as its not a date -

```
with date_cte(created_at) as
(select * from values
('2022-06-10T18::35::57'),
('2022-06-10T18::35::57'))
select to_date('2022-06-10T18::35::57') from date_cte;

100040 (22007): Date '2022-06-10T18::35::57' is not recognized
```

Using timestamp will not work too due to '::' in time portion

```
with date_cte(created_at) as
(select * from values
('2022-06-10T18::35::57'),
('2022-06-10T18::35::57'))
select to_timestamp('2022-06-10T18::35::57','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss') from date_cte;

100096 (22007): Can't parse '2022-06-10T18::35::57' as timestamp with format 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss'
```

Below takes care of both -

```
with date_cte(created_at) as
(select * from values
('2022-06-10T18::35::57'),
('2022-06-10T18::35::57'))
select to_timestamp('2022-06-10T18::35::57','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24::MI::SS') from date_cte;
```

| TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-06-10T18::35::57','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24::MI::SS') |
| --- |
| 2022-06-10 18:35:57.000 |
| 2022-06-10 18:35:57.000 |

Now to compare - just convert in desired format using to_char -

```
with date_cte(created_at) as
(select * from values
('2022-06-10T18::35::57'),
('2022-06-10T18::35::57'))
select * from date_cte
where to_char(to_timestamp('2022-06-10T18::35::57','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24::MI::SS'),'yyyy-mm-dd')='2022-06-10';
```

| CREATED_AT |
| --- |
| 2022-06-10T18::35::57 |
| 2022-06-10T18::35::57 |

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(created_at, 0, 11) as date) = '2022-06-10'
```